# How to "inject" a directory path into a web app for deployment to Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, dependency-injection, jndi, war

I am writing a web app which depends on a directory path for use as a local Maven repository. Now I wonder what is the most idiomatic way to inject this dependency without changing the WAR:

1. Should I use a [Custom Resource Factory](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories) for JNDI,
2. or should I use a [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29),
3. or anything else?

I would prefer a solution which feels obvious for system administrators. The target container is Tomcat, but the solution should not depend on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have used a @Resource injection.